# Line art modifier looks different in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers, eevee-render-engine, npr

I'm trying the new line art modifier and other than a few z-fighting issues it works great! Problem is when I render it looks *horrid:*

Viewport render:
[image: Viewport render]

Actual render in eevee:
[image: Actual render in eevee]

I have no idea what could be causing this, I checked and there aren't any hidden objects that would be visible in the render but not in the viewport, either way I'll link the .blend here:
https://pasteall.org/blend/75af7acbee85431daea7987a7b17eaa3

Comment: That looks like it might be z-fighting.  Do you have "In Front" checked in the View Port display?  I don't know why that's what controls the setting in renders, but it does.

Comment: Whoops you posted a blend file and I didn't see, I'm a dork. I'll go ahead and check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The artifacts in the render are the result of Z-fighting between the strokes and meshes and it's just by chance you see the whole strokes in the viewport and not in the render.  Z-fighting behavior is inconsistent.

To fix this, set the In Front setting under the Viewport Display heading of the Object Properties.

[image: Picture of the Viewport Display ui with In Front checked]

I don't know why this controls how the grease pencil strokes work in the render, but it does.  I've found that I always turn this on with the Line Art modifier, actually.  It seems like it's always needed if the objects are going to be visible at all, because otherwise you get z-fighting behavior.

After setting it in your blend file, I render your picture like this:

[image]